# What are Android Certificates?

Tags: android, security, certificate

Can someone please show me the light on this thing?

What are Android Certificates?

In Settings > Location and security there is an option to install additional certificates. For what purpose?

Are they related only to secure web connections? Or what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capability you are asking about allows one to add certificates for VPN connections.